# Calculate derivatives on Casio Graphics Calculator?

Tags: calculus, calculator

Is there any way I can calculate derivatives using a Casio Graphing Calculator?

Is there a program available for the calculator which can calculate them?

Comment: What specific model of Casio graphing calculator?

Comment: Casio CFX-9850GC Plus

Answer (score 2):

I don't have that model at hand to check for sure, but I think you can get a numerical approximation of the derivative at a point by graphing the function and using the trace feature with derivative turned on in the settings.  Here is [the relevant section of the manual, from chapter 8](http://support.casio.com/pdf/004/fx_plus_chapter08.pdf):

[image: excerpt from section 8-6 of the manual]

Comment: Thanks! I can find the numerical value of the derivative using that function, but what I really need is the actual function itself. Is there any way I can (quickly) work backwards from the numerical value to confirm the derivative I have calculated manually is correct?

Comment: @user8176: I'm pretty sure that your model of Casio won't give you a formula for the derivative.  The best  you could do is probably to get several numerical approximations of the derivative and note the pairs $(x,f'(x))$ from the calculator, then try those values of $x$ in the formula you think is the derivative to see if the values match.  If the values don't match, your formula is probably wrong; if the values do match, it's not a guarantee your formula is right, but it is a quick check.